# Как объявить два шаблона класса, если каждый из них имеет указатель на другой?

Tags: c++, qt, шаблоны-с++

Например, имею два шаблона класса, каждый из которых имеет один или больше указателей на другой:

Класс Object

```
#include "Link.h"

#include <QDebug>

template <class ValueType>
class Object
{
public:
    Object() {}

    ValueType value() const {
        return _value;
    }

    void setValue(const ValueType &value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    void print() const {
        qDebug() << "object:" << value().toString();
    }

    void link(const Object<ValueType> *other) {
        Link *ln = new Link();
        ln->setFromObject(this);
        ln->setToObject(other);
        _links.append(ln);
    }

private:
    ValueType _value;
    QList<Link*> _links;

};
```

Класс Link

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H

#include "Object.h" //упс 
template <class ValueType>
class Link
{
public:
    Link() {}

    Object<ValueType> *fromObject() const {
        return _fromObject;
    }

    void setFromObject(Object<ValueType> *fromObject) {
        _fromObject = fromObject;
    }

    Object<ValueType> *toObject() const {
        return _toObject;
    }

    void setToObject(Object<ValueType> *toObject) {
        _toObject = toObject;
    }


private:
    Object<ValueType> *_fromObject;
    Object<ValueType> *_toObject;
};
```

Сделать объявления класса (как для "нормальных" классов - не шаблонов) типа:

```
template <class T>
class Object<T>;
```

не позволяет синтаксис.

Как следует поступить в подобном случае (без большого количества выкрутасов)?

Например можно использовать один из классов как аргумент шаблона другого

```
template <class ValueType, class LinkType>
class Object
{
    LinkType<ValueType>
...
```

тогда в Link

```
template <class ValueType>
class Link
{
...
    Object<ValueType, Link<ValueType> *_someObject;
```

Но не ясно какой тип должен иметь аргумент другого, так как они равноправны. Является ли этот способ "классическим"?
Есть другие варианты решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если так:

```
template<class T>
class Object;
```

?

Comment: О! Все так просто! :)))